# fabric.loadSVGFromURL when called in a loop always call the last callback

Tags: fabricjs

fabric.loadSVGFromURL when called in a loop always call the last callback, and not all the callbacks in the loop.
Looks like a closure issue in fabric loadSVGFromURL. The code below always print value 2 in console log which tells us that the callback is invoked only for the last iteration.

Code

```
var paths = ['walking-0.svg', 'walking-1.svg', 'walking-2.svg'];
for (var i = 0; i < paths.length; i++) {
    var path = paths[i];
    fabric.loadSVGFromURL(path, (function (i) {
        return function (objects, options) {
            console.log(i); //always print 2, when the expected behaviour is to print all the three number starting from 0 to 2.
            console.log(objects) //print only once, when it should print thrice
        }
    })(i));
}
```

Comment: If you can pop it on a jsfiddle, I think it should be easy to sort, but your 'objects' console log is confusing me (easily done!), so it may be easier to check with a bit of working code to fiddle with.

Comment: I just realised this works fine with version 1.4.0, but with the latest version, i.e. 1.4.4 this is indeed a problem.